# Elasticsearch curator delete action - delete "n" older indices after rollover?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-curator

The following elasticsearch curator *(below)* set-up in `curator-actions.yml` is configured to delete indices based on age filter but I would like to set-up a config that works with rollover as follows:

Only keep the last index and new created rolled-over index -> thus deleting all other indices after a rollover is successful. What is the best way to accomplish this?? Possible with NEST in code?

Here is my current delete action...any help is much appreciated, thanks!

in *curator-actions.yml*

```
action: delete_indices
description: >-
  Delete indices older than 3 days (based on index creation date)
options:
  ignore_empty_list: True
  continue_if_exception: True
filters:
- filtertype: pattern
  kind: prefix
  value: applogging-test
- filtertype: age
  source: creation_date
  direction: older
  unit: days
  unit_count: 3
```

Comment: Can you elaborate the rollover part please ? Dont think I get it. Can’t you just schedule curator to run after rollover ?

Comment: @ben5556 I've done the rollover in the code using NEST for .NET using aliases => Eg:

`PUT /logs-000001 
{
  "aliases": {
    "logs_write": {}
  }
}

# Add > 1000 documents to logs-000001

POST /logs_write/_rollover 
{
  "conditions": {
    "max_age":   "7d",
    "max_docs":  1000,
    "max_size":  "5gb"
  }
}` 
Now, using the curator I intended to config a delete action that deletes all indices except the most recent 2 (eg. the newest index created by the rollover and the latest index that was just rolled over).

I had a go with a count filter type but not got it yet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually easier than you think. You can keep the two most recent indices quite easily with the [`count`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/5.6/filtertype_count.html) filter.  The following example incorporates both the `rollover` action and the `delete_indices` action immediately after it (I used the `conditions` you supplied in the comment above--tune your rollover conditions appropriately):

```
actions:
  1:
    action: rollover
    description: Rollover index associated with alias name
    options:
      name: aliasname
      conditions:
        max_age: 7d
        max_docs: 1000
        max_size: 5gb
  2:
    action: delete_indices
    description: Keep only the two most recent indices
    options:
      ignore_empty_list: true
    filters:
    - filtertype: pattern
      kind: prefix
      value: applogging-test
    - filtertype: count
      count: 2
```

Now, this presupposes that all indices matching prefix `applogging-test` will be rollover-style, and will increment numerically. You can add other options or filters as needed, though.

Comment: You could run this action file frequently, with no danger of indices rolling over more often than your `conditions` provide for. Likewise, no deletions would take place unless there were more than 2 indices matching the `applogging-test` prefix. You could schedule it to run every 5 minutes without concern.

Comment: I totally get this...your solution (exactly as you've detailed here with the condition parameter changes) is working like a charm, thanks again! I can also confirm that scheduling a frequent rollover and deletion has no consequence unless the conditions are met in either which is great :)